# zlib decompress header check error

Tags: python, postgresql, zlib

I have an issue with a dictionary I'm compressing and storing to a postgres database. I can compress the dictionary and decompress it without fault but when I insert it into the database, and then select it back and try to decompress the data I get an error:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Here's a test script I wrote to emulate all the parts:

```
import zlib
import cPickle
import psycopg2

try:
    db = psycopg2.connect( database='*****', user='*****', password='*****',host='******')
    cursor = db.cursor()

except:
    print 'no db'

atom_id = 166503
params = {'submission': 'RVBV4SXLVVDNAAKIG2LIJKZQ', 'campaign': 'p3percybot', 'dob': '2011-03-11', 'rndrpath': '/mnt/webservices/store/p3percybot/rndr/2011-03-11/RVBV4SXLVVDNAAKIG2LIJKZQ', 'outpath': '/mnt/webservices/store/p3percybot/out/2011-03-11/RVBV4SXLVVDNAAKIG2LIJKZQ', 'srcpath': '/mnt/webservices/store/p3percybot/src', 'root': '/mnt/webservices/store', 'inpath': '/mnt/webservices/store/p3percybot/in/2011-03-11/RVBV4SXLVVDNAAKIG2LIJKZQ'}

print params
params_list = []
for k in params :
        param_name = k
        param_value = cPickle.dumps(params[k])
        param_value = zlib.compress(param_value,9)
        param_value = buffer(param_value)
        params_list.append((param_value,atom_id, param_name))

print params_list

sql = 'UPDATE atomparams set value = %s where atomid=%s and name=%s'
cursor.executemany(sql, (params_list))

sql = 'SELECT name, value FROM atomparams WHERE atomid=%s'
cursor.execute(sql, (atom_id,))
result = cursor.fetchall()

print '\n-----------------result-----------------'
print result
for data in result:
   print data[0]
   data_string = zlib.decompress(data[1])
   print data_string
```

Open to any suggestions as to why this is getting messed up in the db. I should note the field type storing the value is of type bytea

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried just comparing the value that goes into the DB and the value that comes out? I don't just mean checking whether they're equal, but looking at the sequence of bytes you get in each case and seeing where they start to differ and how. Is something bad happening where there are zero-bytes or top-bit-set bytes or something? Is your value getting truncated somewhere? That sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary string requires escaping

**psycopg2**

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.Binary

**Postgres Binary String**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html#DATATYPE-BINARY-SQLESC

Comment: I do call buffer on my param_value which prepares it properly for postgres. We have moved this to a new box and this code doesn't work, however we do have a working version of this code on another box...there's both linux boxes using the same version of python and the same postgres db...this is why this is quite puzzling...I've seen this work, however on a new server, it doesn't

Comment: OK, so the code was working before. New environment and it is having trouble. Seems like zlib is not happy.  http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress may need to set some additional args here.

Comment: I did try changing the wbits with the values 8-15 and even tired negative wbits....not sure how to handle buffsize argument though...

Comment: @deecodameeko, @kevpie: mucking about with zlib.(de)?compress args is not productive. It should work OK with the default args. Do as @Gareth McCaughan suggested: print what's going to the db and what's coming back. Amplification: Dont just do `print x`; do `print type(x), len(x), repr(x)` in both cases. Do it on the old box if it still exists. Check for db config issues on the new box.

Comment: @john-machin That is good advice. Maybe even try and decompress your buffer without sending it. See that that works, can't see why it won't but who knows.

Comment: @John-machin there's a good idea, will check that. Db is the same so same config. Thanks for the advice all.